# Convert dataframe to descriptive text via list of lists in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyverse

I admit that this is a poor question title, but I could not think of an appropriate title for this as I'm not quite sure what process I am trying to do here:

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    location = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3),
    organisation = rep(1:6, each = 2),
    project = rep(letters[1:12])
  )

   location organisation project
1         A            1       a
2         A            1       b
3         A            2       c
4         B            2       d
5         B            3       e
6         B            3       f
7         C            4       g
8         C            4       h
9         C            5       i
10        D            5       j
11        D            6       k
12        D            6       l
```

what I would like to convert this into is some text (for use in `leaflet` map popups) that reduces the data in the following way:

> **location A**
>
> ***organisation 1***
>
> project a; project b
>
> ***organisation 2***
>
> project c
>
> **location B**
>
> ***organisation 2***
>
> project d
>
> ***organisation 3***
>
> project e; project f

etc

I have been playing around with making lists and for loops, but am struggling with the correct syntax. I *think* what I should do is create a list of lists such as:

```
list(
  A = 
    list(
      '1' = list('a', 'b'), 
      '2' = list('c')
    ),
  B = 
    list(
      '2' = list('d'), 
      '3' = list('e', 'f'))
)
```

etc, to give:

```
$A
$A$`1`
$A$`1`[[1]]
[1] "a"

$A$`1`[[2]]
[1] "b"


$A$`2`
$A$`2`[[1]]
[1] "c"


$B
$B$`2`
$B$`2`[[1]]
[1] "d"


$B$`3`
$B$`3`[[1]]
[1] "e"

$B$`3`[[2]]
[1] "f"
```

etc, but I want to do this programatically and then access these elements in creating the text. I am trying to do this within the 'tidyverse' approach, and have created both a nested dataframe using

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(location, organisation) %>% 
  nest
```

to give:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  location organisation             data
    <fctr>        <int>           <list>
1        A            1 <tibble [2 × 1]>
2        A            2 <tibble [1 × 1]>
3        B            2 <tibble [1 × 1]>
4        B            3 <tibble [2 × 1]>
5        C            4 <tibble [2 × 1]>
6        C            5 <tibble [1 × 1]>
7        D            5 <tibble [1 × 1]>
8        D            6 <tibble [2 × 1]>
```

and a more typical list-based approach as:

```
library(tidyverse)

loc_names <- unique(df$location)

map(
  loc_names,
  ~ unique(df$organisation[df$location %in% .])
) %>% 
  set_names(loc_names)
```

to give:

```
$A
[1] 1 2

$B
[1] 2 3

$C
[1] 4 5

$D
[1] 5 6
```

but clearly these are only half-finished efforts (I have not brought in the `project` variable yet) and need to be converted to strings for the next stage.

All help is greatly appreciated, particularly if kept within a `tidyverse` approach

Comment: `df %>% group_by(location, organisation) %>% summarise(project = list(project)) %>% summarise(projects = list(setNames(project, organisation))) %>% {setNames(.$projects, .$location)}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following using `Rmarkdown`:

The Idea is to do transform your layout into markdown per group.
This is ~the same as the styling here on SO. You can find the full [cheatsheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZTsr.png).

To get the styling as you want it you need to set the `results='asis'` flag for the chunk. This way the result is rendered as markdown.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown


```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
df <- 
  data.frame(
    location = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3),
    organisation = rep(1:6, each = 2),
    project = rep(letters[1:12])
  )

cat_group <- function(dat){
  cat(sprintf("\n### location %s\n", as.character(dat$location[1])))
  by_row(dat, ~cat(sprintf("
__organisation %s__\n
%s\n", .$organisation, .$projects)))
}

df %>% 
  group_by(location, organisation) %>% 
  summarise(projects = paste("project", project, collapse = "; ")) %>% 
  group_by(location) %>% 
  do(cat_group(.)) %>% 
  invisible
```
````

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: That's very nearly the answer I'm looking for - I would just need to remove the repetition, in your example of 'location A' and 'location B', which should only appear once. Is there a simple edit to achieve this and I will accept your answer? Many thanks